# Сортировка двухсвязного списка

Tags: c++, c, список, двусвязный-список

Нужно оформить сортировку двухсвязного списка, я сделала определенную функцию, но она ничего не сортирует или выбивает с ошибкой. Как сделать сортировку по буквам?

Вот моя структура:

```
struct spis
{
    char name[45];
    float sc;
    float cnt;
    double sq;
    struct spis *v1; // v1 – указатель на предыдущую структуру
    struct spis *v2;
};
```

Вот еще две глобальные структуры:

`struct spis *head, *tail;`

Вот функция для сортировки, которую я не доделала до конца:

```
void sort(spis *p) {
    spis  *pn,*tmp;

    if (p = head) {
        pn = p->v2;
        while (p != NULL) {

            if (strcmp(pn->name, p->name) > 0) {
                tmp = p;
                p = pn;
                pn = tmp;
            }
            p = p->v2;
            pn = pn->v2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexF, исправила

Comment: `if (p = head)` ?

Comment: p=head - значит начало списка

Comment: не смешивайте контейнер и ноды - разделите их и избежите кучи мороки

Comment: `if (p = head)` - данный код не осуществляет сравнение `p` и `head`, он эквивалентен выражению `p = head; if (p) ..` Если вам надо сравнить `p` и `head`, то пишите `if (p == head)`

Comment: @goldstar_labs, ничего не изменилось, все равно выбивает с ошибкой -1073741819.

Comment: Вот вам работающий пример (два типа сортировки): https://pastebin.com/TwN3SiCd (не составит труда переделать функцию-компаратор на сравнение строк)